# selenium while loop not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I'm starting to get the hang of while loops, however when using the while loop on a selenium code, I come up short.

Pretty much I'm trying to replicate a task 10 times, here is what the code looks like

**Main.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://orlando.craigslist.org/search/cta')

owl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a')
res = 1

while res < 10:
    owl2 = owl.click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/header/nav/ul/li[3]/p/a').click()

    res = res + 1
```

here is the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "main.py", line 12, in 
>           owl2 = owl.click()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
>   line 77, in click
>           self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
>   line 491, in _execute
>           return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 238, in execute
>           self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 193, in check_response
>           raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
>   document
>         (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.2
>   x86_64)

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time the DOM is changing or refreshing the `driver` losses the elements it previously located witch cause the error.

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference:
>   element is not attached to the page document

You need to relocate them in order to interact with them. In addition, `click()` doesn't returns any value so you can't assign it to anything

```
res = 1
while res < 10:
    owl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a')
    owl.click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/header/nav/ul/li[3]/p/a').click()
    res = res + 1
```

> Edit

With `for` loop for all the items you can locate the items into a list and click by index

```
size = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a'))
for i in range(0, size):
    owl = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a')
    owl[i].click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/header/nav/ul/li[3]/p/a').click()
```

Comment: this works great, now you don't have to answer this but, how would you do this in a "For Loop". for each listing

Comment: @OwlMan I added an example of `for` loop

Comment: @OwlMan Edited to include all the items.

Answer (score 2):

The error message gives us a clue:

```
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

What's happening here is that you are clicking on a link, and navigating to another page, hence, you get stale element because you're on a different page.
You will want to navigate back to the same page, try something like this:

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

after the click() event.

Comment: still doesn't replicate the task 10 times though

Answer (score 0):

Very simply said: you must start your test case with loop, means "for" must be the first command in your test case and everything afterthat.
Example:

```
def test_case(self):
     login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
     for element in element_to_check:
          assert element
```

won't work. It stops after first cycle. Instead just rewrite your code like this:

```
def test_case(self):
 for element in element_to_check:
      login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
      assert element
```