# Error in Selenium webdriver on clicking on button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've error in Python Selenium. I'm trying to download all songs with Selenium, but there is some error. Here is code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/tigran/Documents/chromedriver/chromedriver')

url = 'https://sefon.pro/genres/shanson/top/'

driver.get(url)
songs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a')


for song in songs:
    song.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a[2]').click()
    time.sleep(8)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
```

And here is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    song.click()
  File "/home/tigran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/tigran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/tigran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/tigran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)
```

Any ideas why error comes?

Answer (score 0):

Before your loop try to add `try:`
Sometimes the document is not attached, so it gives an error

Comment: It didn't work. First song is downloading, but second one gives error.

Comment: Did the second song have the same ```xpath```?

Comment: I'm taking list of songs. It prints all list. But second doesn't work. One time it worked, but I don't know why.

Comment: I understand that, but did the other songs have the same ``` element xpath```

Comment: Here is list's xpath: /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a

Comment: Here is first song's xpath: /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/a

Comment: Copy the ```HTML``` element from the page here

Comment: [link](https://sefon.pro/genres/shanson/top/) here is website. Sorry I couldn't

Comment: It's ```forbidden 404```

Comment: Anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's link [selenium while loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738189/selenium-while-loop-not-working?rq=1). You need to locate elements in loop.
Final code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/tigran/Documents/chromedriver/chromedriver')

url = 'https://sefon.pro/genres/shanson/top/'

driver.get(url)
size = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a'))

for i in range(0, size):
    songs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a')
    songs[i].click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a[2]').click()
    time.sleep(8)
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    time.sleep(5)
```